# How can I use a candle to heat glass/quartz to a specific temp

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Excuse my ignorance of physics. Is it possible to suspend glass or quartz over a candle at a specific distance (in. or mm.) in order to heat the object to a certain temperature, say 300 C. Is there a graph anywhere for something like this? The convection heat transfer above a candle flame? I'm trying to find the temperatures ABOVE a flame but can only find the temperature OF a flame.

Or say I put a funnel upside down over a candle, leaving room for oxygen at the bottom, will that force the heat up out of the top of the funnel and create more temperature control in regards to my first question?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The reason you aren't probably finding anything is because this most likely depends heavily on the specs of the candle: dimensions/type of wax, length of free wick, width of wick, type of wick, etc. That's a lot of variables to keep track of.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really possible to answer like this.  It's going to depend on a lot of factors.  You might need to control the situation way more than possible with an easy setup.  I'm not sure _how much_ it would vary; but the heat (and therefore temperature) depends on the amount of fuel/air in the combustion, which you would have minimal control unless you made a fairly elaborate setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate the plume temperature above a fire using correlations from Heskestad or McCaffrey, listed respectively below:

$$T_0=25(\dot Q ^{2/5}_c/(z-z_0))^{5/3} + T_ \infty$$
$$T_0=22.3(\dot Q ^{2/5}_c/z)^{5/3} + T_ \infty$$

Where $T_0$ is the centreline plume temperature, $\dot Q_c$ is the convective heat release rate of the fire, $z$ is the height above the fire source, $z_0$ is the virtual origin and $T_ \infty$ is ambient temperature (all temperatures in Celsius). Virtual origin can be estimated (Heskestad) by:

$$z_0/D=-1.02+0.083 \dot Q^{2/5}_c/D$$

Within the flame region, one typically assumes a constant temperature (the flame temperature of say 800 °C). This was all derived from work with heptane, methane burners.

Some issues you may encounter:

- This is for undisturbed plumes, which is impractical in "the real world".
- You can't put an item in a plume at 300°C and expect it to heat to 300°C - there is one more major factors at play: heat gains and losses to the quartz plate both by convection and radiation. You will need to determine your energy gains and losses to predict your plate temperature.

Another interesting piece of work which may help you has been carried out by NIST (http://fire.nist.gov/bfrlpubs/fire05/PDF/f05141.pdf) which characterises heat fluxes at various locations above a candle flame.